# How to encode a struct back to a bytes buffer

Tags: json, go

I am making a API request and the response I get back is a bytes.Buffer.
I then json decode that into my struct:

```
resp, status, err := // api call that calls http client do and returns byte buff

result := MyStruct{}
err = json.NewDecoder(response).Decode(&result)
```

I know want to take my struct, result, and gzip it.

**Should I be using a json decoder to get the value back?**

I want to then take that decoded json so I can then gzip it eventually.

Also, I am confused between a byte array, bytebuffer and then these readers.  Is this hierarchy like java?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store your struct as json, the simplest way is usually to use [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal), as in:

```
b, err := json.Marshal(&myStruct)
```

b will in this case be a byte slice ([]byte). This can later be gzipped using the `gzip` package. For instance, to gzip the bytes to a file, you could use:

```
f, _ := os.Create("/tmp/s.gz")
defer f.Close()

w := gzip.NewWriter(f)
w.Write(b)
w.Close()
```

If you want to, you can bypass creating the byte slice by using [`json.Encoder.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.Encode) directly instead.

```
f, _ := os.Create("/tmp/s.gz")
defer f.Close()

w := gzip.NewWriter(f)
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&myStruct)
w.Close()
```

Depending on where you want to store or send the gzipped json, you can replace the parameter `f` used in `gzip.NewWriter(f)` to be any object that implements `io.Writer`. For instance, you can send the gzipped response using `http.ResponseWriter` directly in a handler:

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    myStruct := ...          // Get struct from somewhere
    gz := gzip.NewWriter(w)
    json.NewEncoder(gz).Encode(&myStruct)
    gz.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused by your question but maybe this helps a bit:

Assuming you would use the standard [`http.Client`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client) your HTTP call would be done via `Client.Do` which returns an [`*http.Response`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Response).

You can read the response body from the `Body` field which is of type [`io.ReadCloser`](https://godoc.org/io#ReadCloser). This is actually just an interface that combines the [`io.Reader`](https://godoc.org/io#Reader) and [`io.Closer`](https://godoc.org/io#Closer) interface. If you know the response is `json` you can now create a `json.Decoder` using [`json.NewDecoder`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#NewDecoder) which accepts any `io.Reader`.

Its important to keep in mind that all types *implicitly* implement `io.Reader` by having the following function defined on them:

```
Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

Just as the `*http.Response` `Body` field is an `io.Reader` any `bytes.Buffer` implements `io.Reader` because it implements the [`Buffer.Read`](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer.Read) function.

In contrast a `[]byte` (byte array) is a scalar type that does not implement any functions on its own. Therefore `[]byte` does not implement `io.Reader` so you can not just pass this into `json.NewDecoder`. If you want to decode JSON from a byte array/slice you should probably just use [`json.Unmarshal`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshal) or create a `bytes.Buffer` from your `[]byte` using [`bytes.NewBuffer`](https://godoc.org/bytes#NewBuffer) and then again pass that to the `json.Decoder`.

The same concepts apply for encoding JSON back but this time instead of an `io.Reader` you need an `io.Writer` and a [`json.Encoder`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#NewEncoder).

Comment: If you already have all the data as `[]byte` then I prefer using `json.Marshal`. If you work with streamed data and/or you just have an `io.Reader` the `json.Decoder` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`io.Reader` and `io.Writer` are interfaces specifying object behaviour regardless of it implementation. `bytes.Buffer` is data structure implementing both `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`. array is just core language data structure similar with others languages have. Most interfaces advantage is you can operate with them uniformly despite underlying implementations. For example io library has `func TeeReader(r Reader, w Writer) Reader` which returns a Reader that writes to w what it reads from r. You can use it to gzip response as you read and decode it.

```
SomeWriter, err := os.OpenFile("some/File", os.O_WRONLY, os.ModePerm ) //gzip to file for example
gzipper := gzip.NewWriter(SomeWriter) //but can be any Writer
tee := io.TeeReader(response, gzipper)
//and then
err = json.NewDecoder(tee).Decode(&result)
```